# jQuery Mobile vs. smoothState.js?

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobile, mobile-website, usability

If I'm already using jQuery Mobile -- is http://css-tricks.com/add-page-transitions-css-smoothstate-js/ (http://weblinc.github.io/jquery.smoothState.js/) possible / worth it to implement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really don't see a benefit of using jQuery Mobile with **smoothState.js**. jQuery Mobile already can do everything **smoothState.js** can, you only need to learn how. Though **smoothState.js** has everything better described, plus you don't need to use gazillion different page events. But to use them both you would need to turn off jQuery Mobile Ajax handling.

Basically I would like to see  **smoothState.js** approach used inside jQuery Mobile framework.

My advice stick to jQuery mobile if you really need its UI, for everything else use  **smoothState.js**, of course if seamless navigation is something you desire.

Comment: Due to the fact that I'm using jQuery Mobile with its structure CSS (I've made my own UI from scratch) your answer does confuse me somewhat. I'm always looking for the simplest alternative, and from what I know jQM won't be properly cleaned up, have scrolling working etc. until at least 1.7. I do however enjoy its toolbar and popup widgets - and from what I understand its structure CSS has a lot of hacks to make things work on older devices. If you were me, would you switch to smoothState.js?

Comment: In this case you should switch to smoothState.js completely, specially if you have your own UI. Also instead of using whole jQuery Mobile framework you should rebuild it and use only jQuery Mobile UI components you need. You can do it here: http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/ This way you will make sure inner jQuery Mobile logic will not mix with smoothState.js.